# Given $2^n - 1 \mid 3^m - 1$, how large must $m$ be compared to $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $m,n$ be natural numbers such that $2^n - 1 \mid 3^m - 1$. By results from Bugeaud-Corvaja-Zannier, say Theorem 3 of [this paper](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1710-01.pdf) , we know that for any constant $C > 0$ we must have $m > Cn$ for sufficiently large $n$. Is it known whether we can do better than that? Heuristically I would expect $m$ to be very large compared to $n$.

I would be happy to see any improvement over $Cn$, or even an average statement that $m$ has to be large compared to $n$ most of the time.

Comment: No, it is unknown.

Comment: Can you give a (rigorous) example of such an "average statement"?